# How to search list of values in DataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datatable

I have a DataTable with some n number of columns and array of string to search in this table.
I want to search all these strings in DataTable and store matching strings in list.

Columns in DataTable are dynamic so using below code I got list of Columns from DataTable.

But not sure how to search and get matching records using LINQ or any other technique with best feasible approach.

```
DataColumn[] cols = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToArray();
```

Comment: "without impacting performance of the application" everything affects performance, especially when you search in a huge DataTable strings

Comment: You want to search strings and if you found them store them in a list. So you have a set of search-strings and the desired result is a subset which contains only those strings that were found?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Yes, you're right.. I mean without impacting much.. best possible approach..

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Yes, that is the expectation. I want to store matching result set in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
DataColumn[] cols = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToArray();
var rows = dt.AsEnumerable();
List<string> foundList = searchList
    .Where(s => rows.Any(r => cols.Any(c => r[c].ToString().Equals(s))))
    .ToList();
```

But this would be more efficient:

```
HashSet<string> searchStrings = new HashSet<string>(searchList); // or use a HashSet<string> instead of a list in the first place
List<string> foundList = new List<string>();
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    IEnumerable<string> matches = cols
       .Select(c => row[c].ToString())
       .Where(searchStrings.Contains); // Contains is O(1) operation
    foreach (string match in matches)
    {
        foundList.Add(match);
        searchStrings.Remove(match);   // Remove is O(1) operation. It has another advantage: at the end searchStrings contains only strings that were not found
    }
}
```